# Connecting to EC2 Windows host from Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

When I use the recommended [rdesktop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html) to connect to Windows EC2 host I see from Archlinux:

```
$ rdesktop 54.254.180.73

ATTENTION! The server uses and invalid security certificate which can not be trusted for
the following identified reasons(s);

 1. Certificate issuer is not trusted by this system.

     Issuer: CN=EC2AMAZ-I5MV8JK


Review the following certificate info before you trust it to be added as an exception.
If you do not trust the certificate the connection atempt will be aborted:

    Subject: CN=EC2AMAZ-I5MV8JK
     Issuer: CN=EC2AMAZ-I5MV8JK
 Valid From: Thu Mar  5 16:06:01 2020
         To: Fri Sep  4 16:06:01 2020

  Certificate fingerprints:

       sha1: 98f1e92f9b9a3b57f4b2a23177f1bbe1a9afeb2c
     sha256: 8e9f1a2e5497c972b56b8300f6e2ec3f59c8903103984cb5456a237c9a7b2d45


Do you trust this certificate (yes/no)? yes
Failed to initialize NLA, do you have correct Kerberos TGT initialized ?
Failed to connect, CredSSP required by server (check if server has disabled old TLS versions, if yes use -V option).
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Especially when [rdesktop](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rdesktop-announce/AddglSNxK90) doesn't appear maintained.

Any tips to connect to a Windows host?

Comment: Have you already checked this guide on Kerberos TGT? Looks relevant to the error you received: https://github.com/rdesktop/rdesktop/wiki/Network-Level-Authentication-(NLA)

Comment: Maybe it'd be an easier setup with VNC?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34933/376095

Comment: Does your Windows system has CredSSP patch in place? It's possibly blocking the connection. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4295591/credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation-error-when-to-rdp-to-azure-vm for remediation (it's about Azure, but it doesn't really matter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Instead of rdesktop, the [FreeRDP: A Remote Desktop Protocol Implementation](https://www.freerdp.com/) seems to better accommodate this **CredSSP required by server** issue.

```
xfreerdp /u:"Administrator" /v:ec2-3-1-49-118.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```